# Security of app using Parse servers

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, parse-platform

I am using Parse servers for my app, and I am concerned about people getting into the code of the app and changing the code that communicates directly with Parse.

For example, if I save a score to the database and I want to update it with a new score by the user, I have to write that code within the app. However, if someone were to change the code and hardcode in a score that wasn't earned, they technically could.

Is there a way to prevent this?

(When I say getting into the code, there is a way to do this using a jailbroken device. I don't know if Apple has fixed this, but about a year ago someone I know showed me the code to an app that is on the App Store.)

Comment: forgetting about parse, what would make you confident a user score was earned under any circumstance?

Comment: There is no 100% safe solution, there might always be a way for an attacker to cheat your system. A low hanging fruit would be to validate the score against an upper limit, lets say a player can only reach a maximum score of 1000 in your game, you can reject every score higher than that and possibly even ban the player that sent the score for trying to cheat.

Comment: You can also use a time based mechanism with some salted key which is verified by the server to check it came from your code. Again any scheme is crackable by a person who spends enough time on it...